# Minor bug with HTML/CSS menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to put up a website but I came across some problems with the dynamic menu.
To be more specific, I've adapted a template to include a dropdown menu: some menu items include a sublist that appears when the cursor is over; besides, the main item should change background at mouse over AND when the user is on that specific page.

What I'd like to get is that whenever you are visiting a subpage, only the main menu item is highlighted, but unfortunately this won't happen. I can't make the main item switch background when it is selected, and I have no idea why.

Here's the CSS involved:
    /* menu */

```
#menu {
    background: #65b63a;
    clear: both;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #65b63a;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#menu ul li.active a, #menu ul li:hover {
    background:url('images/menuover.jpg') repeat-x bottom;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:10pt;
}    

#menu ul li {
    background: #65b63a;
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border-right:1px #aeaeae solid;
}

#menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 17px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#menu ul li.sub a{
    background-image:none;
}

#menu ul li ul{
    display:none;
}

#menu ul li ul li{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


#menu ul li:hover ul{
    background:none;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    padding-top:30px;
    margin:0;
    font-size:10pt;
}

#menu ul li ul a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    background:none;
}

#menu ul li li{
    width:200px;
    font-size:10pt;
    background-image:none;
    text-transform:none;

}
```

And here's the HTML involved:

```
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  <!-- this one is a single item -->
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Chi? Dove? Quando?</a> <!-- this should be "active" but it isn't -->
                    <ul>
                        <li class="sub"><a href="chi.html">Chi siamo</a></li>
                        <li class="sub"><a href="dove.html">Dove siamo</a></li>
                        <li class="sub"><a href="orari.html">Orari</a></li>
                        <li class="sub"><a href="staff.html">Lo staff</a></li>
                        <li class="sub"><a href="contatti.html">Contatti</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I believe the problem is in the CSS, but I can't make it work.

Thanks in advance,
Lorenzo

P.S. As a reference, you can find a raw of the website @ http://www.pansepol.it/raw
The homepage is and example of single-itemed page, while "Viaggi di Gruppo" > "Asia" is an example of a multi-leveled. As you can see, while navigating to this last page, "Viaggi di Gruppo" isn't highlighted whatsoever.

EDIT:-----------------------------------------------------------

Silly me, it was that simple.
I applied the "active" class to the `<li>` element and corrected the CSS as Justus and Raad suggested.

Now the code reads:

```
#menu ul li.active a, #menu ul li:hover {
    background:url('images/menuover.jpg') repeat-x bottom;
}
```

and

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Chi? Dove? Quando?</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="sub"><a href="chi.html">Chi siamo</a></li>
                    <li class="sub"><a href="dove.html">Dove siamo</a></li>
                    <li class="sub"><a href="orari.html">Orari</a></li>
                    <li class="sub"><a href="staff.html">Lo staff</a></li>
                    <li class="sub"><a href="contatti.html">Contatti</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Everything works smoothly.

Thank you,

Lorenzo

Comment: I tried with your code and I get this http://jsfiddle.net/rVabR/ is it your expecting result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you made a minor mistake in your CSS:

```
#menu ul li.active a, #menu ul li:hover {
```

Should be:

```
#menu ul li.active, #menu ul li:hover {
```

Because you want the `li` to show the background-image, not your `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
I tried correcting the code as you suggested, but that didn't change anything...

Any other clue?

Comment: On the website the `active` class is added to the `a` element. Make sure you add the classname to the `li` (as in your question code)

Comment: You may use the big accept button if I pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

On the "Home" page, the "active" class is being applied to the `<li>` element; but on the  "Viaggi di Gruppo" > "Asia" it is applied to the `<a>` element instead. It needs to be one or the other, then adjusted in the css if necessary.